# How to add logic in a joining tables SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have to create one table based on several tables.

The result table contains several columns : some columns are taken directly from the source tables but other columns require more logic.

In the query below (short example of my problem) you have

```
SELECT
    cntr.cntr_id, 
    cove.eff_date, cove.end_date,
    amou.amount AS paid_start_date, amou.amount AS paid_curr_date
FROM 
    msa_contract cntr, msa_coverage cove, msa_amount amou
WHERE 
    cntr.cntr_id = '1234'
    AND cove.cntr_id = cntr.cntri_id
    AND amou.cvrg_id = cove.cvrg_id
```

my problem comes in the two last columns (`paid_start_date`  and `paid_curr_date` ). These two columns are sourced by the same column `amou.amount`.

The column `paid_start_date` should take `amou.amount` only when `amou.start_date = cntr.start_date`

The column `paid_curr_date` should take `amou.amount` only when `cntr.cancelled = 'No'`

I don't really see how to integrate these two rules in my query. Can you help me with this?

Comment: I note in 20 months of being a member of Stack Overflow you've not received a single answer worth accepting.

Comment: @Stu is that a commentary on the effectiveness of the answerer or the inattention to follow-up of the poser? :D

Comment: @CaiusJard the latter.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The column paid_start_date should take amou.amount only when amou.start_date = cntr.start_date

```
CASE WHEN amou.start_date = cntr.start_date THEN amou.amount END as paid_start_date
```

> The column paid_curr_date should take amou.amount only when cntr.cancelled = 'No'

```
CASE WHEN cntr.cancelled = 'No' THEN amou.amount END as paid_curr_date
```

You didn't say whether some other value should be present if the predicate is false, so I didn't put an ELSE. If CASE doesn't find any predicate that is true, and there is no ELSE, the result is NULL

---

As a footnote, I don't know what tutorial you followed to get advice to join your data like that, but it must be quite an old one because we've been encouraging this form for about 30 years now:

```
FROM 
    msa_contract cntr
    INNER JOIN msa_coverage cove ON cove.cntr_id = cntr.cntri_id
    INNER JOIN msa_amount amou ON amou.cvrg_id = cove.cvrg_id
WHERE 
    cntr.cntr_id = '1234'
```

It's virtually the same as what you write, except where you put `,` we put `INNER JOIN` and whatever `x.y = a.b` in the WHERE part relates the data together, we put that after the word `ON` that follows the right hand table name/alias